# Generate random strings using 3 different string values

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

net web application and I need to generate a random string related to three different values I pull from database.
The first value corresponds an integer, the second value corresponds a date in the format(dd/mm/yy) and the third value is a char. 
How can I create a single random string combining this three different values?

Hope your help

Comment: Do you want a random string or one derived from those three inputs.  (Because one derived from inputs isn't random)

Comment: How can it be random if those 3 field affect it?  Are you talking about generating a random number and adding those 3 values to it to make it unique?  This would be similar to a Guid.

Comment: `Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + val1 + val2 + val3`

Comment: I dont know exactly what you want but if you dont need to use the actual values you can always use the ascii value of each char and apply some algorithm to the integer values. You can also then later then extract that same values, using the algorithm.

Comment: what I mean with random is if create a single string combining the numbers and characters of this three fields somothing like this "aDfMc0zzIDaf2gxj0Okq5dYmFSoYmO5Xh2GyGktA2J3UQ285XKF4k7FidssCH3MTUWeSB5lapGfNHtLNbAmv"

Comment: @user773456 - Why don't you just use `Guid.NewGuid()`?

Comment: also, this `random` string, does it need to be reversable back to the original input seeds?? I'm seeing a pattern here where a badly proposed question is creating a HUGE spiral of further clarifications

Answer (score 2):

if i understand the question correctly, then:

```
var newString = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", intValue, dateValue, charValue);
```

.. if i understand that is :) (tho not sure about the `random` part as to whether the above addresses that or not. if not, add a Guid() into the mix too)

**[UPDATE]** - whip up a console app and try the following to get randomness from your inputs. this is a bit shizzy, but demonstrates the randomness:

```
class Program
{
    static string RandomizeString(string inputString)
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        // throw the input string into an array, sort it randomly
        // then join the resulting array back to a single string
        var result = inputString
            .ToArray()
            .OrderBy(x => rnd.Next());

        return string.Join(string.Empty, result.Select(x => x.ToString()));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // explicitly simulate the 3 inputs that you mention
        int intValue = 23;
        DateTime dateValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Char charValue = 'd';

        // package to a single concatenated string
        var newString = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", 
            intValue, dateValue.ToString("dd/MM/yy"), charValue);

        // show 'original version'
        Console.WriteLine(newString);
        // now the 'random' one
        Console.WriteLine(RandomizeString(newString));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: hokey cokey, gotcha. i'll see if i can stir it up a bit

Comment: @jimtollan - `dateValue` is not being formatted to the OP specs (dd/mm/yy).

Comment: ooops - my bad, sorted. rushing about too much tonite reading kids stories and popping back for edits (no wonder they 'hate' me lol) :).